# Correct way to use FormData

Tags: typescript

I have to use an instance of `FormData` for the code I'm working on.

When I write:

```js
const form = new window.FormData();
```

I get the error

> Property 'FormData' does not exist on type 'Window'

My tsconfig has:

```
{
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
}
```

So I was slightly surprised to see that window doesn't have `FormData`.

---

I tried defining `FormData` on `window`:

```js
declare global {
    interface Window {
        FormData: FormData;
    }
}
```

In which case I get the error:

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature

---

**How can I create a new instance of `FormData` and pass Typescript compilation?**

Comment: What are your compiler target and TS version?

Comment: @ritaj target is `"es5"`, TS version is 3.4.5

Answer (score 1):

Without using window.formData....
You should use directly :

```
const formData = new FormData();
```